# How to align left when already in flushleft environment in Latex

Tags: alignment

After \centering, I keep creating new \begin{flushleft} which I think is very inefficient and is there another way to align left without creating so many of these environments[image]?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

    \begin{flushleft}
    If $f(x) = x^{n}$, then  $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$ and $f''(x) = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$.
    \newline
    \hfill\break
    \\
    The addition formula for cosine is $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ = $\cos\alpha$$\cos\beta$ - $\sin\alpha$$\sin\beta$.
    \\
    The addition formula for tangent is
    \newline
    \\
    \centering
    $\tan(\alpha+\beta)$ = 
    $\frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}$
    \newline
    \\
        \begin{flushleft}
            The bionomial theorem states that
            \newline
            \\
            \centering
            $(a+b)^n$ = $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i}a^ib^{n-i}$
            \begin{flushleft}
                for any real numbers a and b and for any integer n $\ge$ 0
                \newline
                \\
                The modulus of a complex number z = a+bi is $\left|z\right|$ = $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the argument of z, $\varphi$ = arg z satisfies a =  $\left|z\right|$cos$\varphi$ and b = $\left|z\right|$sin$\varphi$, so $\tan{\varphi}$ = $\frac{b}{a}$.
                \newline
                \hfill \break
                \\
                The general formula for the integral of a power of x is
                \newline
                \\
                \centering
                $\int x^ndx$ = $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ + C,
                \begin{flushleft}
                    \raggedleft so
                    \newline
                    \centering
                    $\int\limits_{0}^{2} x^3 dx$ = $\left[\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^2$ = 4
                    \begin{flushleft}
                        The determinant of a 2 $\times$ 2 matrix is given by the formula
                        \newline
                        \\
                        \centering
                        $\det$
                        $\begin{pmatrix} 
                            a & b\\ c & d
                        \end{pmatrix}$


                    \end{flushleft}
                \end{flushleft}

            \end{flushleft}
        \end{flushleft}

    \end{flushleft}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use ``\\`` nor `\newline`, use blank lines instead. Don't use `$`...`$` for displayed equations, use `\[`...`\]`. Do that and remove all `\centering`s and `flushleft`s and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* errors in your code.

1. Don't split formulas
2. Math is math, so `n$\ge$0` should be instead `$n\ge 0$`
3. `\newline\\` is wrong
4. For displayed equation use `\[...\]`

There are many other fixes I made in the code below. Study them.

I loaded `parskip` because you seem to be wanting it. For a document like this it can be a choice. Don't use it for real papers: just use a blank line for separating paragraphs.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

If $f(x) = x^{n}$, then  $f'(x) = nx^{n-1}$ and $f''(x) = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$.

The addition formula for cosine is $\cos(\alpha+\beta) = \cos\alpha\cos\beta - \sin\alpha\sin\beta$.

The addition formula for tangent is
\[
\tan(\alpha+\beta) = \frac{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta}{1-\tan\alpha\tan\beta}
\]

The binomial theorem states that
\[
(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}a^ib^{n-i}
\]
or any real numbers $a$ and $b$ and for any integer $n\ge 0$

The modulus of a complex number $z=a+bi$ is $\lvert z\rvert=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and the argument 
of $z$, $\varphi=\arg z$ satisfies $a=\lvert z\rvert\cos\varphi$ and $b=\lvert z\rvert\sin\varphi$, 
so $\tan{\varphi}=\frac{b}{a}$.

The general formula for the integral of a power of $x$ is
\[
\int x^n\,dx =\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + C,
\]
so
\[
\int_{0}^{2} x^3 \,dx = \left[\frac{x^4}{4}\right]_0^2 = 4
\]

The determinant of a $2\times 2$ matrix is given by the formula
\[
\det\begin{pmatrix} 
    a & b\\ c & d
    \end{pmatrix}
=ad-bc
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm a first-year Maths student and have only started learning Latex. Thanks for the help and I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @AchuanChen You're welcome! As you see, typing LaTeX is not so difficult, once you get into the mood. :-)